# How to create a public class with internal required objects in C# for protecting assembly information?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a public class with internal required objects as follows:

```
public class Person
{
   internal required string? FirstName {get; init;}
   internal required string? LastName {get; init;}
}
```

The reason behind the above class is that I want to create an assembly that will be added to another project. The project will only be able to access class members through class object and will not be exposed.

The reason for this approach is to keep assembly information protected and secured. However, I am getting error for having public class and internal object members.

I expect to create Public class with internal required members so that I don't have to define constructor for the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not allowed. You cannot use a `required` modifier in this case.

The [proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/required-members#accessibility) states:

> It is an error to mark a member `required` if the member cannot be set
> in any context where the containing type is visible.
>
> - If the member is a field, it cannot be `readonly`.
> - If the member is a property, it must have a setter or initer at least as accessible as the member's containing type.

I would suggest that you write a constructor instead:

```
public class Person
{
    internal string? FirstName {get; init;}
    internal string? LastName {get; init;}
    
    public Person(string? firstName, string? lastName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

After all, `required` is not some magic that entirely replaces constructors. There are still many differences between them. For more info, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74583049/5133585).

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper. I had this implementation already but was wondering if there is any better solution. Looks like there isn't at the moment.